# Angular renderer performance for manipulating css properties vs dynamic css properties

Tags: css, angular, renderer

In an Angular application i have typically used the `renderer` with `elementRef` to manipulate an element's css properties dynamically.

Now that we have the wonderful world of `--dynamic-css-properties`, id like to know what the Angular community recommends as it relates to performance and best practice. I have not been able to find any discussion on the topic as of late.

Should we all be moving away from using the renderer for this purpose now that we have dynamic css properties?

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. See what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what [not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I was afraid of that being the case, just that the official angular site suggests that developers post questions to SO tagged as Angular. I can delete the question.

Comment: Don't, it doesn't mean you cannot get a useful answer ;)